# Can we change Windows 10 behavior to be MacOS like?

Tags: macos, windows, fullscreen

I’m using Windows 10 but am more comfortable as a Mac User and I really miss some behaviors I’ve come to expect. I own a 32'' 4K monitor and now with Windows 10, my windows get maximized at full everytime is not ideal.

Have any other fellow users which alternate between Mac and Windows have found a solutions for this item? My research for tools yields results about changing the looks of windows more like mac and that's not what I'm interested in. I want the rezise/maximize behavior to make me as efficient as in MacOS.

I hope you can point me into the right place to find a solution for this.

Are windows controls on Windows 10 modifiable?

Comment: I’ve edited this slightly and will migrate to super user. If they don’t want it we will gladly host this back on Ask Different, but let’s get their take on this first.

Comment: @bmike thank you, you are very kind.